# Comparison application

Tags: c#

I'm making a comparing section, which I've just started typing, trying to get something working. It's working now, but as you can see its pretty messy.  I feel this could be done in one or two less queries, or I should break it apart into smaller methods.

```
foreach (XMLObject source in Sources)
{
    var matchedElement =
        destList.FirstOrDefault(s.ElementName == source.ElementName);
        // checks to see if it exists in one list but not the other

    if (matchedElement == null) // element is in one list and not the other
    {
        var alter =
            lstAlteration.FirstOrDefault(
                a => a.ElementName == source.ElementName && a.ChangeInfo.ChangeFrom == source.ElementName);
            // check to see if the the element is a Removal (Changed From would not be blank)

        if (alter == null) // Removal has not been triggered
        {
            alter = new Alteration
                        {
                            ElementName = source.ElementName,
                            ChangeInfo = new ChangeDetail( {ChangeTo = source.ElementName}
                        };
        }
        else
        {
            alter.ChangeInfo.ChangeTo = source.ElementName;
        }

        lstAlteration.Add(alter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var source in Sources.Where(x => !destList.Exists(s => s.ElementName == x.ElementName))
{
    var alter = lstAlteration.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ElementName == source.ElementName
                                 && a.ChangeInfo.ChangeFrom == source.ElementName);

    if (alter == null) {
        alter = new Alteration
                    {
                        ElementName = source.ElementName,
                        ChangeInfo = new ChangeDetail()
                    };

        lstAlteration.Add(alter);
    }

    alter.ChangeInfo.ChangeTo = source.ElementName;
}
```

- Sorter
- Only one .ChangeInfo.ChangeTo = source.ElementName; execution

Comment: Shouldn't where clause be "**not** exists in destList"?

Comment: I like that the "not exists" is filtered at the get-go, fundamentally simplifying the proceeding logic; allowing the loop to be focused on what its supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small note as I think [Peters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/14749/peter-kiss) answer is pretty clean and tidy.

You may want to consider a consistant naming convention.  For the same list type you use a prefix of **lst** (lstAlterations) and a suffix of **List** (destList).  I'm not a huge fan of this convention (others might beg to differ) so instead I would probably look at naming the lists something like just *alterations* and *destinations*.

Comment: you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest the following:

```
        foreach (XMLObject source in Sources)
        {
            if (destList.Exists(s.ElementName == source.ElementName))
                continue;
            // perform a lightweight check
            if (lstAlteration.Exists(a => a.ElementName == source.ElementName 
                                        && a.ChangeInfo.ChangeFrom == source.ElementName)) 
            {
                lstAlteration.Where(a => a.ElementName == source.ElementName
                                         && a.ChangeInfo.ChangeFrom == source.ElementName).First()
                                         .ChangeInfo.ChangeTo = source.ElementName;
            }
            else
            {
                lstAlteration.Add(new Alteration
                            {
                                ElementName = source.ElementName,
                                ChangeInfo = new ChangeDetail( {ChangeTo = source.ElementName}
                            });
            }
        }
```

1. Reduce nesting
2. Perform lightweight checks instead of instance materializing.
3. Compact code, ommiting extra variable